# Soldering MEMS sensor

Tags: pcb, soldering, soldering-iron-station, solder-paste, solder-mask

I have a problem with soldering the LIS2DH12 MEMS sensor accelerometer. I searched for soldering recommendations but I do not understand exactly how to solder.

I couldn't find the needed heat and  time requirements.

The datasheet says:

> leave "Pin 1 indicator" unconnected during soldering.

The datasheet refers to JEDEC J-STD-020  documents, but I couldn't understand again.

I want to use solder cream for pads because a soldering stencil too expensive for me (25 dollars.) Do you any advice for soldering?
[image]

[image: This is the datasheet soldering part]
[image]
[image]

You can reach datasheet and JEDEC J-STD-020 documents links below:

https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lis2dh12.pdf

https://file.elecfans.com/web1/M00/20/D6/ooYBAFmk2XaASEEKAAt3ul2CRuY690.pdf

https://shop.ipc.org/document-numbers/ipcjedec-j-std-020

Comment: Solder paste + hot air gun.

Comment: These are simply a pain to solder manually. Use a reflow oven. Seriously, I've been doing hacky hand soldering on these way too many times and it never turns out well, always a gamble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hot air gun would allow the solder on all pads to melt at the same time and hence align the part due to surface tension of the solder.

If you are using a soldering iron. Solder one pin and and check that the part is aligned properly. The ends of the pads are visible from the sides, so you can check that they align with the pads on your PCB.

With parts of that size you will pretty much need a microscope. With some luck and experience you might do without though.

The track between pads 2 and 3 is not recommended as the space does not allow a solder mask "bridge" to prevent the solder from combining from the pads to one big ball of solder. It's not a huge problem though if it's too late to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived very late to this question, but could I will give my opinion in case that it helps someone. Could it be that it is referring to the big bottom pad on the center?

In application notes from accelerometers it is normally recommended to not solder the central pad if possible, since that couples more the stresses from the PCB to the device. I found application notes from Analog Devices and Invensense indicating also to not solder pin 1. They make it clear they talk about the central pad, but it might be that it is a default documentation they use for all their products (even the ones without a central pad).

If that is the case, it is really poorly explained.